# itextsharp dll not converting color code properly

Tags: asp.net

An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in itextsharp.DLL but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Unknown color format. Must be #RGB or #RRGGBB

it says when converitng a html page

```
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=TestPage.pdf");
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    form1.RenderControl(hw);
    StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 100f, 0f);
    HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
    pdfDoc.Open();
    htmlparser.Parse(sr);
    pdfDoc.Close();
    Response.Write(pdfDoc);
    Response.End();
```

Comment: Can you please supply some sample code that is making use of itextsharp with the input which is causing the error

Comment: can u look again i have edited the question

Comment: do you have a sample of the html that is giving the error?

Comment: it is very big file could u give me your email address so that i can give you the html code it was very big file thats why i am asking

Comment: you can add the file as a Gist on Github and share the link to the gist here. (https://gist.github.com/)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Istiak1992/e212cfee5d7b8bf0157929b43c041e05

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of notes.

1. [HtmlWorker is being deprecated](http://www.lowagie.com/itext530) in [iTextSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/iTextSharp/). You should look into using [iTextSharp XML Worker](https://www.nuget.org/packages/itextsharp.xmlworker/) which you can install using Nuget.
2. The html provided in the gist link has some inconsistencies, your `<link>`, `<meta>`, `<p>`, `<br>` and `<img>` tags does not have any closing "`/>`" tags. Browsers might be lenient when omitting closing tags, but when you start using iTextSharp's Html to PDF conversion tools, it requires the closing tags.

Herewith a method I used to successfully convert your html after fixing the minor issues in the html using iTextSharp's `XMLWorkerHelper`.

```
    private static void WritetHtmlToPdf()
    {
        using (var stream = new FileStream("C:\\Temp\\htmlsample.pdf", FileMode.Create))
        {
            using (var document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 100f, 0f))
            {
                var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream);
                document.Open();

                using (var filestream = new FileStream("C:\\temp\\sample.html", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, document, filestream, Encoding.UTF8);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I've tried to update your code to use the `XMLWorkerHelper`, but I cannot guarantee that it would work as is, but it should give you an idea:

```
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=TestPage.pdf");
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

        Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 100f, 0f);
        pdfDoc.Open();

        XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(sw, pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream, Encoding.UTF8);

        pdfDoc.Close();
        Response.Write(pdfDoc);
        Response.End();
```

Hope this will help you.